# How to add multi multiplicity to mxgraph nodes?

Tags: connection, nodes, edges, mxgraph, multiplicity

I'm using mxgraph for bpmn workflow in my web application.
So I need state some rules for nodes. For example:

1. Start node has no input.
2. Start node has just one output to others except notification node.
3. Start node has 0 ore more out put to notification node.

I can't specify this state with multiplicity.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Put domain info into cells' values. Override `mxGraph#validateEdge`, implement your rules there based on source and target cells' values (alternatively override `mxGraph#isValidConnection` if you don't care about providing a error message).